# Error crops up after weeks of running a website

Tags: .net-3.5, com, dll, interop, windows-server-2003

I have a website based on Vs2008, .NET 3.5SP1 C# code.  One of the functions requires it to interop with a COM-based DLL that creates PDFs.

About once every 3 to 4 weeks, anything COM related (e.g. generating PDFs) is completely hosed.  I get the following error:

> Creating an instance of the COM
>   component with CLSID
>   {7A91D523-4F04-42BD-8441-4C15B9D7C04F}
>   from the IClassFactory failed due to
>   the following error: 800401f7.

I looked up 800401f7 and it means *Some error in application program*.

If I do iisreset, everything is back to normal for a few weeks.

Why am I getting this error and what does it really mean?

Comment: Could memory leak be an issue here?

Comment: @shahkalpesh No, plenty of memory on the system when this happens.

Comment: I am not sure how to check this. Is it possible that limit on number of open files could be exceeding here?

Comment: Same thing just began occuring to me. Are you still clueless on this?